# Получение доступа к переменной

Tags: android, java

Приветствую всех!
Подскажите, можно ли получить доступ к переменной commandMap в данной ситуации:

```
public class MainSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    //Та самая переменная
    private final Map<String,String> commandMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener   sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() 
    {
       @Override
       public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) 
       {
             //Необходимо получить доступ здесь

       }
    }
}
```

Пробовал:  *`MainSettingsActivity.this.commandMap.put()`* но выдает ошибку *`No enclosing instance of the type MainSettingsActivity is accessible in scope`*

Comment: Проблема в том, что в методе класса не можешь получить доступ к одному из полей того же класса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статическая переменная инициализируется при загрузке класса. У вас **sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener**  -  статическое поле класса, а **commandMap** нет, **commandMap** инициализируется когда произойдет создание экземпляра объекта класса **MainSettingsActivity**, т.е когда у вас будет существовать и жить в памяти **sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener**, то программа может даже и не знать о том, что создаст когда то **commandMap**.

Есть два выхода:
1 - делать **commandMap** статической
2 - убрать у **sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener** static

Comment: Спасибо, что подробно разжевали. Объяснили просто и понятно!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить к определению **commandMap** ключевое слово **static**.

Возможно все дело в модификаторе доступа, попробуй объявить **commandMap** как **protected**

Comment: Спасибо, изменение на **static** решило проблему. Теперь я могу обращатся к переменной как  **MainSettingsActivity.this.commandMap**, так и **MainSettingsActivity.commandMap**.

Comment: @imholynx: Эээ... Вы бы сначала подумали, вам нужен один _общий_ `commandMap` на все экземпляры класса, или для каждого объекта свой? Так запросто менять семантику программы, знаете ли, очень смело.

Comment: Один commandMap на все экземпляры мне не нужен. Их у меня и не будет. Это меня и смущает. А есть предложение?

Comment: Хм, кого не будет? Ваш класс `MainSettingsActivity` -- синглтон?

Comment: Да, он будет один.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте так:

    static MainSettingsActivity instance = new MainSettingsActivity();

и обращайтесь к ней:

   @Override
   public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) 
   {
       MainSettingsActivity.instance.whatever;
       // ...
   }